# Binding a list of uris to collection view of images

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of object data for images that I am retrieving from the backend.

The response has a format similar to this: `images = {[0]:{AbsoluteUri: "https://foo.bar/image.jpg"}, [1]:{AbsoluteUri: "https://foo.bar/image-banana.jpg"}`

Where images has a collection of images with image property data.

I set this two properties:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Uri> ImagesList
        {
            get => imagesList;
            set
            {
                if (imagesList == value)
                    return;

                imagesList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImagesList));
            }
        }
```

I have this snippet:

```
var images = await FetchMediaService.CallImagesEndpoint();
ImagesList = images;
```

which sets the data coming from the backend to the ImagesList property.

But I'm confused on how the XAML binding works here:

```
<Grid x:Name="layout">
        <CollectionView x:Name="cv" BackgroundColor="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout 
                    SnapPointsAlignment="Start" 
                    SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    ItemSpacing="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainPage}, Path=HingeWidth}" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="0" Margin="0" 
                           WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainPage}, Path=ContentWidth}"
                           HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainPage}, Path=ContentHeight}">
                        <Frame Margin="20" BackgroundColor="White">
                          <Image
                                   Source="{Binding AbsoluteUri}" //What should this bind to? 
                                   Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        </Frame>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
```

I added ImagesList to ItemsSource of CollectionView but I'm not positive to how set the individual uri I get back from the server on each image in the collection. How do I properly set the ImageUri?

Comment: if `ImagesList` is a collection of `Uri` objects, then you would want to bind to the `AbsoluteUri` property.

Comment: @Jason you're right, it's the same value. It doesn't matter either way. How do I make sure it binds to the single uri in the image source?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  You are currently binding to ImageUri, which is NOT a property of the Uri class (unless you are using your own Uri class and not System.Net)

Comment: ImageUri is just a string property I made up. Ok let's step back and say, I forget using ImageUrl. How do I bind it properly?

Comment: read my first comment - use AbsoluteUri

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment. I tried doing so: Source="{Binding AbsoluteUri}" but nothing appear in my collectionView. Is there a good way to debug binding issues?

Comment: add a Label to your template and bind it to AbsoluteUri to verify the data actually contains valid urls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208000/discussion-between-euridice01-and-jason).

Comment: Use . instead of AbsoulteUrl as you are binding to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we need to generate the C#.net class for JSON response string,

```
 public class imageurl
{
    public string AbsoluteUri { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, installing "Newtonsoft.Json" by Nuget package to parse JSON string,

Finally, write below code to parse above JSON response.

```
   public async void GetJSON()
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("REPLACE YOUR JSON URL");
        string stringJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        urls= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<imageurl>>(stringJson);
    }
```

The entire code here.

```
public partial class Page21 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<imageurl> _urls;

    public List<imageurl> urls
    {
        get { return _urls; }
        set
        {
            _urls = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("urls");

        }
    }


    public Page21()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        urls = new List<imageurl>();

        GetJSON();

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public async void GetJSON()
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("REPLACE YOUR JSON URL");
        string stringJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        urls= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<imageurl>>(stringJson);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
public class imageurl
{
    public string AbsoluteUri { get; set; }
}
```

There is one article about this, you can take a look:

http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2017/04/xamarinforms-consuming-rest-webserivce_17.html